# javascript function that causes a redirect to 404 on many site

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

why does this cause a 404 error

```
(function(){
   var getownProperties = Object.keys(window);
   var propsLen = getownProperties.forEach(function(e,i,a){
       window[e] = undefined;
});
})()
```

Comment: Likely at the point where you're trying to assign `undefined` to `window.location` or such…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit the case of `window.location = undefined`, you are using the API to open a different URL. In this case, `undefined` will be interpreted as a string, the string `'undefined'`, which changes to the relative URL `./undefined` from the current page.

If you try this on http://example.com, `window.location = undefined` redirects to http://example.com/undefined. On most domains that's probably going to be a non-existent page and hence 404, on others you may trigger some other behaviour.

You cannot actually replace many/most of the global properties, since they're implemented as non-configurable property setters (meaning a function will handle your attempted assignment, in the case of `window.location` triggering a redirect). E.g.:

```js
const foo = {
  set bar(value) {
    console.log("You can't replace me so easily,", value);
  }
};

foo.bar = 'baz';
```